# App built with Install4j does not launch post installation on Windows 10 machine

Tags: install4j

When I install an java/swing application built with Install4j on Windows 10, it gets installed under default folder C:\Program Files(x86)\MyApp folder but when I try to launch by doing  double click on Launcher then it gives an error dialogue with permission issue message :"Windows can not access the specified device, path or file. You may not have appropriate permission to access them". When I launch the same by doing a right click on launcher  and then choosing the option "Run as administrator" then it launches fine. I checked the permission on the launcher file for the user I logged in and it was there. Kindly suggest me how to go about this. Is this an user configuration issue on the Windows 10 machine or something else. This problem has been seen recently.

Comment: You should post it in http://superuser.com/

Comment: You need read and execute permission for the user.

Comment: I am able to access the installation folder and launch another application.